# Bad SQLITE update Performance

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I am fairly new in **SQL**(now working on **SQLITE** application) and it is a section in my app when i try this piece of Code:

```
public void addSong(LibrarySong song){

    for(int i=0; i<intoPanel.getComponentCount(); i++)  //Check if doublicates exist
        if(song.getName().equals(intoPanel.getComponent(i).getName()))
            return;


    intoPanel.add(song);    

    //Add the song to the database table
    try{
        Container.DataBase.connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO '"
                + Container.libWindow.libInfoWindow.currentLib.getName()+ "'"   //Table Name
                + " (PATH,STARS,DATE,HOUR) VALUES ('"
                + song.getName() + "'," + song.stars + ",'"
                + song.dateCreated + "','" + song.hourCreated + "')").executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException sql){ sql.printStackTrace(); };
}
```

**The Problem:**
The above method just add the song to a Jtable and then to database table.The problem is that the performance is too bad for the database.Why might this happen? i use the statement somewhere wrong or i have to to the update with different way?Thanks for reply.

Comment: Well, you're using `PreparedStatement` wrong for one. I suggest you learn to use the `setXXX` methods for setting the parameters.

Comment: @Kayaman you mean values(?,?,?,?) it will improve the performance?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it will improve your code. You don't want to write bad code, do you? You can also reuse prepared statements, so that'll give you a performance improvement if you're doing that a lot.

Comment: @Kayman thanks man i want to ask something more.When i use a statement and execute update i have to close the statement and then execute the next update?

Comment: How would closing and recreating be reuse? Google for prepared statement batching for optimized inserts.

Comment: How often are you calling this function? In a loop?

Comment: @Cl i am calling it every time the user drag&&drop a folder into a Jtable.Then the method will be called for every file of folder with the extension(.mp3,.ogg,.something whatever i choose) it is done into a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most expensive part of accessing a database is not the execution of the statement itself, but all the synchronizations done for transactions.

By default, each SQL command is put into an [automatic transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29), so you get the overhead for all of them.

If you have multiple updates, you should group them into a single transaction:

```
Container.DataBase.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
...
for (...)
    addSong(...);
Container.DataBase.connection.commit();
```

Comment: CL.1)I used the default commit of sqlite(the true) so if i now use AutoCommit false i have every time i create a table or rename item of row or insert or... to press .commit() 2)And something more if i make a rename and and insert at the same time it will cause  error? Thanks for reply!

Comment: CL. OMG MAN I TRYIED IT NOW AND I GOT SOCKED WHAT SPEED WAS THAT IT WORKED LIKE YEAH!Thanks (if you have something more faster let me know) That was tremendous for me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem boils down to that every write to disc is done by sqlite itself in default mode

you could enable

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL
PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL
```

To make use of the operating system disc buffer.
Just remember to flush/commit everything regularly or at break points after inserts. Only risk is if there is sudden powerloss or reboot, your database might end up corrupted.

https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

Comment: This operation if done very fast with a for(loop) from a Thread and the database dies slowly....

Comment: Yes, because the database only can write once per spin cycle of the harddrive. That is why you need the pragma statements so it doesnt write directly to disc but to OS buffer which flushes it to disc.

Without pragma I can insert 70.000 rows in a few minutes. with pragma that is 2 seconds.

The only thing to be consious off is to make regular backups of the database because if the power goes theres a big risk that the database is irrepairably corrupted.

Comment: Also, learn to use prepared statements. Then you can just recycle the statement with different variables. that is also a huge speed improvement. You are now basically rebuildng a stringbuilder object every loop, making a new query... all unneeded overhead. Prepare your query once, then feed it the variables needed in every new loop.

Comment: Thanks man very usefull i want to ask you something more you mean i have to connection.commit very frequently?

Comment: Yea. Just push the flush statement regularly in "quiet" times where you can "suffer" the small delay.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the component usage is suboptimal: the first for-loop.

Use a

```
Set<String> songNames = new HashSet<>();

if (songNames.contains(song.getName())) { return; }
songNames.add(song.getName());
```

Or maybe a Map for other uses.

And use the prepared statement with placeholders `?`. This escapes single quotes too. And is safer.